# how multiple users in one login page

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 type of users Adopter and donor I made users

```
 myref1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Adopters");
 myref2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Donors");
```

And I have one login page Im trying make like if user was Adopter he should go to Adopter page
and if was donor he will go to Donor page !

but when i try to write loign for adopter or donor it take me to the both pages how i can make check each user go to his page when entring information

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            flag=0;
            if(Ad_Email.getText().toString().equals(""))
                Ad_Email.setError("Enter Email");
            else if (ad_pass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                ad_pass.setError("Enter Password");
            else
            {
                

                myref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds1:snapshot.getChildren())
                        {

                            Adopter a=ds1.getValue(Adopter.class);
                            if(Ad_Email.getText().toString().equals(a.ad_Email)&&ad_pass.getText().toString().equals(a.ad_pass))
                            {
                                flag=1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                        if(flag==0)
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Invalid User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                        {
                           // Toast.makeText(Login.this,"valid User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Adopter_System.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                //donor

                myref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds1:snapshot.getChildren())
                        {

                            Donors a=ds1.getValue(Donors.class);
                            if(Ad_Email.getText().toString().equals(a.d_email)&& ad_pass.getText().toString().equals(a.d_pass))
                            {
                                flag=1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                        if(flag==0)
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Invalid User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                        {
                            // Toast.makeText(Login.this,"valid User",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Donor_page.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

i guess i should add if condition but im not sure how help please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user node and have both donors and adopters as users but add the userType to user model so that the model will look something like this:

```
User
 -email
 -dof
 -gender
 -name
 -pass
 -phone
 -userType
```

then you just check the userType and take the user to the corresponding page.

Comment: okay but later i will need to add admin user and i dont think write admin in user type is good idea